# Set autoscroll position on mouse move

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to update scroll bar position when I click on image and move picturebox. It is always at the beggining, it only moving on the right side (horizontall) and down (vertical).

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

            ....

            Point currentMousePos = e.Location;
            int distanceX = currentMousePos.X - mouseX;
            int distanceY = currentMousePos.Y - mouseY;
            int newX = pictureBox1.Location.X + distanceX;
            int newY = pictureBox1.Location.Y + distanceY;

            if (newX + pictureBox1.Image.Width + 10 < pictureBox1.Image.Width && pictureBox1.Image.Width + newX + 10 > panel1.Width)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(newX, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            }
            if (newY + pictureBox1.Image.Height + 10 < pictureBox1.Image.Height && pictureBox1.Image.Height + newY + 10 > panel1.Height)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, newY);
            }
    }
```

Comment: So the user can drag a picture box on a form? Which scroll bars are you talking about?

Comment: @JohnArlen . No, my picturebox is in a panel, which has set Autoscroll on true, and if image is bigger than the panel it showing the scrollbars. On mouse move I move picturebox in the boundaries of panel, operation like that one in Acrobar reader when you have hand cursor. But my scorbars don't act normally, they don't moving from beggining, only spread on other side. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I honestly feel i still need some clarity...what you are looking for. Do you want like the scroll bar should work when you hold the picture with mouse and drag it up, like in acrobat reader and google maps?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need to change the `AutoScrollPosition` of the parent panel and not play around with the `Location` points of the `PictureBox`.  After all, the scroll bars of the parent panel are already taking care of the position of the `PictureBox`.

Try something like this (by the way, my code only does this when a button is pressed, otherwise, I think it would be a weird user interface design):

```
private Point _StartPoint;

void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    _StartPoint = e.Location;
}

void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    Point changePoint = new Point(e.Location.X - _StartPoint.X, 
                                  e.Location.Y - _StartPoint.Y);
    panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X - changePoint.X,
                                          -panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y - changePoint.Y);
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

LarsTech's code isn't 100% correct. 2 notes:

1. Note that if slider is moved, then the same point on screen changes it's coordinates relative to `pictureBox1` (as `pictureBox` moved with moved slider). Therefore we want to use the screen coordinates (`Control.MousePosition` instead of `e.Location`).
2. Changing `panel1.AutoScrollPosition` causes the move of `pictureBox` relative to `mouseCursor`, so the `pictureBox1.MouseMove` event is fired again, even if cursor didn't move on the screen. Adding `_StartPoint = Control.MousePosition` prevents unwanted scrolling.